# How to use script tags in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, templates

I am trying to use a html and CSS template on create-react-app. I can convert all of the HTML to JSX without any issues and render the CSS just fine. I cant get the Script tags that home with the template to work though

Comment: please provide an example of the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you would write script tags in Reactjs the same way you would in HTML. Like this:

```
<script src="fooLink.js"></script>
```

(fooLink.js being any link.)

If you want to go further with React, try looking at this article:
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Or post the code you are having trouble with so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand but can't you add the script tags to your index.html file . The one where you have a div (usually) targeted by the render function of ReactDom (render( , document.getElementById('my target div'))

Answer (score 0):

> React works with classes (ES6) and functions which are called as
>   components. you can create one and  import the created component in
>   your jsx (written inside the render() of the component)

```
//your first component(js)
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class ComponentOne extends React {
 render() {
   return <div>some text or {value}</div>
 }
}
//your second component
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ComponentOne from 'your path here';
class ComponentTwo extends React {
render() {
 return <ComponentOne>;
}
```

You can learn more from https://reactjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save react-script-tag
```

then

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ScriptTag from 'react-script-tag';
class Demo extends Component {
 render() {
    return (<ScriptTag isHydrating={true} type="text/javascript" src="some_script.js" />);
}
}
```